# Mixpanel JQL returning indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, exception, indexof, mixpanel, jql

I have a JQL query in mixpanel which should return result based on two different events. Here are the steps:

1. First event after filtering would return some array of values as **result**.
2. Second event should use that **result** and return the required values after some filtering.

JQL query as below

```
function main() {
var date_range = {
    from_date: "2017-08-02",
    to_date: "2017-08-02"
};
var firstEventResult = Events(date_range).map(function(event) {
  return (event.name === "country" && event.properties.sector === "IT") ? event.properties.Area: null;
}).filter(function(v) {
    return v;
});
return Events(date_range).map(function(event) {
    return (event.name === "state" && firstEventResult.indexOf(event.properties.Area)) ? event.properties.message: null;
}).filter(function(v) {
     return v;
 });
}
```

In the above code, firstEventResult.indexOf() is returning error as "indexOf is not a function". But, firstEventResult is returning an array like below

```
[
  "Delhi"
  "Punjab"
  "Kerala"
]
```